# Pushforward of vector field multiplied by real valued function

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, pushforward

Let M and N be smooth manifolds:
$$\mathbb{R}\xleftarrow{g} M \xrightarrow{h}N\xrightarrow{f}\mathbb{R}$$
and of course:
$$TM\xrightarrow{h_*}TN$$
I need to show that:
$$h_{*}(gX)f=(g\circ h^{-1})h_{*}Xf$$
where $X\in TM$. Tried by substituting $f\rightarrow g\circ h^{-1}$ but it doesn't make sens. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $Y = gX$. The pushforward then becomes $(h_*Y)_q(f) = Y_{h^{-1}(q)}(f\circ h)$. Then you can reenter your substitution to obtain: $g(h^{-1}(q))X_{h^{-1}(q)}(f\circ h)$ or equivalently $(g\circ h^{-1})h_*X(f)$.