# do Carmo Riemannian Geometry Exercise 2.3: definition of $\nabla$ for an immersion

Tags: riemannian-geometry, connections, submanifold

The following is Exercise 3 of Chapter 2 of my Brazilian edition of do Carmo's *Riemannian Geometry*:

> Let $f: M^n \to \overline M^{n + k}$ be an immersion from a differentiable manifold $M$ to a Riemannian manifold $\overline M$. Assume in $M$ the Riemannian metric induced by $f$:
> $$
> \langle u, v \rangle_p = \langle df_p(u), df_p(v) \rangle_{f(p)}.
> $$
> Let $p \in M$ and $U \subset M$ be a neighborhood of $p$ such that $f(U) \subset \overline M$ be a submanifold of $\overline M$. Let $X, Y$ be vector fields on $f(U)$ and extend then to vector fields $\overline X, \overline Y$ on an open subset of $\overline M$. Define
> $$
> (\nabla_X Y)(p) = \text{tangential component of } \overline \nabla_{\overline X} \overline Y(p), 
> $$
> where $\overline \nabla$ is the Riemannian connection of $\overline M$. Prove that $\nabla$ is the Riemannain connection of $M$.

My questions are:

- $X$ and $Y$ are vector fields on $f(U) \subset M$. Then $\nabla_X Y(p)$ does not make sense. Shouldn't it be $\nabla_X Y(f(p))$? Also, $\nabla$ is not a connection on $M$, but on $f(U)$, isn't it? So what does the problem want us to prove?
- What does "tangential component" mean?

Comment: Yes. It's sloppy writing by identify $U$ as $f(U)$. Since $\overline{M}$ is a Riemannian manifold, each tangent space at $f(U)$ split into tangent space of the submanifold and its orthogonal complement. Tangential component obviously the projection onto tangent space of submanifold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bit of abusing notation here. The goal is to define $\nabla $, which is a connection on the tangent bundle of $M$. Thus the goal IS to define $\nabla _X Y(p)$, where $p\in M$ and $X, Y$ are local vector fields of $M$ around $p$. (I think it is very important to know that they are not defining something at $f(p)$: there might be $p\neq q$ so that $f(p) = f(q)$)

The way to do so is

(1) push-forward the local vector fields $X, Y$ to $\mathrm df(X), \mathrm df(Y)$ respectively, if $X, Y$ are on $U$, then $\mathrm df(X), \mathrm df(Y)$ are on $f(U)$ (they abuse notations here, identifying $X, Y$ with $\mathrm df(X), \mathrm df(Y)$)

(2) extend $\mathrm df(X), \mathrm df(Y)$ to a local vector fields $\overline X, \overline Y$ respectively on $\overline M$ around $f(p)$, and

(3) define $\nabla_X Y(p) := \text{tangential component of }\overline\nabla _{\overline X} \overline Y (f(p))$ (Note that it is $f(p)$ on the right hand side. I guess it is a typo) As suggested in the [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3776061/do-carmo-riemannian-geometry-exercise-2-3#comment7774138_3776061), the tangent space at $T_{f(p)} \overline M$ split into $df (T_pM)$ and $(df (T_pM))^\perp$, the orthogonal complement. The tangential component are taken with respect to this decomposition. Thus the more precise definition should be
$$\nabla_X Y(p) :=(\mathrm df)^{-1} \bigg(  \text{tangential component of }\overline\nabla _{\overline X} \overline Y (f(p))\bigg)$$

I suppose they went on to show that $\nabla$ is well defined, independent of the extension $\overline X, \overline Y$. Indeed $\nabla $ is the Levi-Civita connection on $M$ with respect to the pullback metric
$$\langle u, v \rangle_p := \langle df_p(u), df_p(v) \rangle_{f(p)}.$$

Comment: I guess the choice of $U$ would make $f|_U$ embedding no ? Therefore $U$ and $f(U)$ diffeomorphic.

Comment: Yes (I think I don't understand your comment, can you be more direct/specific?) @SiKucing

Comment: It is said in the question that $U$ is a nbd of $p$ such that $f(U)$ is a submanifold of $\overline{M}$, which i interpret as embedded submanifold. With this choice, $f|U$ is embedding and therefore we can't have $f(p)=f(q)$ for $p\neq q$ isn't it ?

Comment: Ar I see. My point is that there could be $q\notin U$ so that $f(q) = f(p)$. Think of the immersion $f:  \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$, $f(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$. It is important to know that $\nabla$ is defined on $\mathbb R$, but not on the image $\mathbb S^1$. @SiKucing

Comment: @ArcticChar To prove that $\nabla$ so defined is a connection, I need to prove, for example, linearity with respect to $X$ (with differentiable functions as coefficients). Now, to prove that I would like to have a transformation of the kind 
$$
df(g X) = (g \circ f^{-1}) df(X), 
$$ 
and then to extend $df(X)$. Does such a relation hold? If not, how to prove this linearity?

Comment: Did you show that $\nabla-XY $ is well defined, independent of the extension $\overline X, \overline Y$? @DaniloGregorin

Comment: @ArcticChar yes, using the argument that only  the values of $\overline X, \overline Y$ at $f(p)$ "matter", so to speak

Comment: I found this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2310404/pushforward-of-vector-field-multiplied-by-real-valued-function which seems to be exact what I need. I just need to translate it to my notation

Comment: Giving it a second thought, I would need $f$ to be a diffeomorphism, wouldn't I?

Comment: Did the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69066/tangential-component-of-a-riemannian-connection) help? @DaniloGregorin

Comment: I appreciate you linking the question, but it didn't help much. In fact, as I understand it, the answer is wrong. He doesn't show that differentiable function "drop out" of the nabla operator, and more fundamentally, he doesn't make a distinction between $M$ and $f(U)$. Of course, I must be missing something, since the answer has 10 upvotes.

Comment: @DaniloGregorin I sort of agree with you. Jesse missed the proof about precisely that LOL. The point is, I would prefer to write another answer instead of writing it here via comments (which is very hard to read). I would post an answer to that question.

Comment: I have asked another question about this point precisely: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3778019/do-carmo-riemannian-geometry-exercise-2-3-definition-of-nabla-for-an-immersi

Comment: Interesting, somehow I cannot see that question. @DaniloGregorin will post an answer there.